# Call function in another website from a button on my site?

Tags: javascript, curl, request

So, to be specific, this site: https://www.overbuff.com/players/pc/Hizu-1730
Has a button right below the "Player X hours ago" which lets you update the info on that profile.
I see that the little button has data-type refresh-button, data-action {sameurl}/refresh and data-autoclick false.
Now I tried just opening https://www.overbuff.com/players/pc/Hizu-1730/refresh but that did nothing, so I'm a bit lost.

I want to be able to click on a button on my own site that refreshes the info on the overbuff profile (so, simulate pressing that little button).

Is that possible?
Via some kind of request or cUrl or something like that?

My site is just a little collection of 6 overbuff profiles (mine and my friends) collected via cUrl, it's easier for us to check everyones profile in just a single page than going to every profile one by one on the real site.
The only problem is that, this way the profiles are not updating, as you have to manually press that button which only works on the real site.
So I would like to add an update button to be able to refresh the info via my site.

Sorry for the poor english :)

Answer (score -1):

When inspecting the element, and traking the network requests, you can see that te request is made by POST

Comment: Would I be able to call the refresh via cUrl then?

Comment: you should use  curl -X POST your-request